# Slickgrid: How to exclude a row from grouping. Or how do I add grandtotal row of all grouping

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Example:
http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping

THis example gives total only at each grouping level, i want to get total of all grouping.

If i add totals as new row it also gets grouped, i want to exclude it.
Is there any option available for this?

Answer (score 1):

i've done below in similar problem.

```
   function filter(item) {
    if (item["YourTotalColumnName"]) {
        if (item["YourTotalColumnName"] == 'YOUR TOTAL WORD') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function filterClear(item) {
    return true;
}
```

when you group something and clear grouping you can do like that:

```
function groupBySomeColumn() {

    dataView.setFilter(filter);
...
...
}

function clearGrouping() {
    dataView.setGrouping([]);

    dataView.setFilter(filterClear);
}
```

I hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

To control the behavior of the data aggregation, you would have to implement your own aggregator. The set of built in aggregators can be seen in the source of [slick.dataview.js](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/slick.dataview.js).

If you are using one of those default implementations, you can "hack" a solution by declaring 2 levels of data grouping with the outer most layer being on a junk data column that has the same value for every data entry. I don't suggest taking this route, but wanted to state that it "is" possible without a completely custom implementation.

```
dataView.setGrouping([
 {
    getter: "myJunkColumn",
    formatter: function (g) {
     return "";
    },
    aggregators: [ new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("data") ],
    aggregateCollapsed: false,
    lazyTotalsCalculation: true
 },
 {
   getter: "year",
   formatter: function (g) {
     return "Year(s): " + g.value + " <span style='color:green'>(" + g.count + " items) </span>";
   },
   aggregators: [ new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("data") ],
   aggregateCollapsed: false,
   lazyTotalsCalculation: true
 }]);
```

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/411jvL4m/)